# Why we need SELECT FOR UPDATE in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, relational-database, oracle12c

A database will automatically figure out how to process two or more transactions in parallel (as serializable schedules) by overcoming the read-write conflicts (using locking). By default there will be isolation among them.

So why do we still need to lock any data in the database by using statements like `SELECT FOR UPDATE`? Why can't we proceed with whatever we want in a transaction block?

```
Begin transaction
//queries
//commit
End transaction
```

Answer (score 14):

> why we can't proceed with whatever we want in a transaction block?

Because in Oracle, [readers don't block writers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/data-concurrency-and-consistency.html#GUID-1D60EFCC-03F4-4A04-B099-1B4DE5D02C47). If you `select` from a table you don't lock it and there is no transaction. So, imagine you do:

```
select col1, col2 into l_col1, l_col2
from table1
where ...;

if (<some logic based on l_col2>) then
  update table1 set col2 = something where col1 = l_col1;
end if;
```

That's fine; but if two sessions run that code at the same time, one session could update the row *between* the other session selecting and performing its update - causing a lost update, or incorrect logic as the state wasn't actually as expected.

If instead you do `select ... for update`:

```
select col1, col2 into l_col1, l_col2
from table
where ...
for update;  -- or: for update of col2

if (<some logic based on l_col2>) then
  update table1 set col2 = something where col1 = l_col1;
end if;
```

then the row selected from the table **is** locked by the first session when it does `select for update`, so a second session has to wait for that transaction to complete before it can obtain the lock, and it will see the state of the row *after* the first update has applied. No lost update, no confusion.

You can also lock rows you don't want to update, as [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-6A1C2FD9-9476-4F8D-A2E4-2C967D7F8C08) says:

> The `SELECT` statement with the `FOR UPDATE` clause (`SELECT FOR UPDATE` statement) selects the rows of the result set and locks them. `SELECT FOR UPDATE` lets you base an update on the existing values in the rows, because it ensures that no other user can change those values before you update them. You can also use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` to lock rows that you do not want to update, as in Example 9-6.

And you can tweak the behaviour:

> By default, the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` statement waits until the requested row lock is acquired. To change this behavior, use the `NOWAIT`, `WAIT`, or `SKIP LOCKED` clause of the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` statement. For information about these clauses, see Oracle Database SQL Language Reference.

If the `select for update` is in a cursor loop then it also allows you to do

```
  update table1 set col2 = something where current of <cursor>;
```

> When `SELECT FOR UPDATE` is associated with an explicit cursor, the cursor is called a `FOR UPDATE` cursor. Only a `FOR UPDATE` cursor can appear in the `CURRENT` OF clause of an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement. (The `CURRENT OF` clause, a PL/SQL extension to the `WHERE` clause of the SQL statements `UPDATE` and `DELETE`, restricts the statement to the current row of the cursor.)

Rows selected by the cursor query are locked as they are fetched. (But the table itself isn't locked.)